# Delete Directories Based on Existing Active Directory Accounts Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am looking for a way to use PowerShell to generate a list of account names from Active Directory in a specific OU and then compare that list to another list generated from a network share containing the user's Home Folder that they are connected to on logon.

The purpose of this would be to compare both lists and then **DELETE** any folder that is **NOT** present in the list of account names taken from Active Directory.

The OU I will be using is nested as such:

```
domainname.org | People | Internal | Users
```

This OU has roughly 25,000 Names (the ID number of each user).

The directory structure is a little more complicated. It's divided into three main directories and each directory has the location name which then contains the Home Folder of the users.

An example would be:

```
\\user-storage\Users\Division1\LOC1\USERID
```

Where USERID is the Name listed in the OU.

All of the users in this OU are in the exact same group as well, so if that makes it easier or helps in any way, that is also a way to go.

Comment: You could just take the usernames from AD and then take the index of the last "\" once you have that take the remaining character which should be the `userid` then select where `userid` doesnt match in the AD username array

Comment: So the name of the folder is the Name attribute in active directory yes? Also do you have anything so far we can build on

Comment: @Matt Yes that is correct. 

Well, what I had was completely blown out of the water by what TheMadTechnician posted. I'm a complete novice with PowerShell and what I had cobbled together makes me weep when I compare it to his short and simple script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a regex match. Pretty sure you can still do that even with 2500 items.

```
$UserNames = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Internal,OU=People,DC=domainname,DC=ORG" | Select -ExpandProperty samaccountname
$UserRegex = ($UserNames | ForEach{[RegEx]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\user-storage\Users\*\*\*" -Directory | Where{$_.Name -notmatch $UserRegex} | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

So that will look at all of the folder 5 levels deep within the \user-storage\users folder, and check it against the list of users. If it's not found it removes it recursively. I put a `-WhatIf` on it so that you can test it without losing data. `-Force` makes it delete the folder even if it has things in it still.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. Now I'm sure I'm missing something entirely trivial here, but when I run this, I get the error. "`Get-ADUser : Directory object not found`".

Should I be running this from a specific location, not just a workstation with access to the network share?

Comment: You would need to verify the path for the searchbase. Pull up any user in that OU and make sure that it looks right. So long as your login has access to query AD, and the computer that you are on is a domain member that code should work fine.

Comment: I figured it out. I went into ADSI edit and looked at the distinguishedName of the OU. Turns out that I had to place everything in the reverse order. So it was `"OU=People,OU=Internal,OU=Users,DC=domainname,DC=ORG"`. I also added `-Recurse` so it would delete child items.

Once I remove the `-WhatIf` though, I get an error message that says, _"Remove-Item : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less 
than 248 characters."_ 

So I'm going to try to sort that out next.